# Where is IEnumerable.Do in Rx v4.0?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm in the process of upgrading to Rx v4.0(since we're also upgrading to the .Net Framework 4.0), and I can't figure out where the extension method IEnumerable.Do went. Is it gone?

Comment: should be part of mscorlib but I could be mistaken

Comment: I see an extension for `Enumerable2.Do<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, ...` but I don't see any for just `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

Download Interactive Extensions instead, here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27203

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of Interactive Extensions (backported extensions for `IEnumerable`) was separated after gold release of Reactive Extensions.

Just install NuGet package `Install-Package Ix_Experimental-Main` it'll work again.